# how can i make my js code select the right html page to choose?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, search-engine

So I have a search engine for my country's states ( made with html, css and js)  and for each state I want to make an html page, so when I go to the search bar and type the state's name and I click the search icon it shows the html page that belongs to that stat (there are 48 html page)

```
function select(element)
{
    let selectData = element.textContent;
    inputBox.value = selectData;
    icon.onclick = ()=>
    {
        webLink = `https://www.google.com/search?q=${selectData}`;
        linkTag.setAttribute("href", webLink);
        linkTag.click();
    }
}
```

I tried this way, but it make a research on the state in google, I don't want that.
I want to show my html page

I also tried this :

webLink = `htmls/?q=${selectData}`;
linkTag.setAttribute("href", webLink);
linkTag.click();

i removed the google link and ive out the name of the folder in which the html pages are stored now when i click enter an index page comes out and i have to choose which html page to show manually, how can i make it choose automatically?

Comment: You say you don't want the search button to do a google search, yet you set the link to a google search page. What are the URLs to your own pages?

Comment: i've set the google link just to test if its working or not. the pages are stoored in a folder in my localdisque i dont have URLs

Comment: Do you have a single template which you use for every state, or do you have separate *.html file for every state (48 *.html files)?

Comment: the html pages are separat, there are 48 html page

Comment: Rather than a "search", list all available "states" in a `<select>` with each one as a different `<option>` where `<option value="page_for_that_state.html">state name</option>`.  If you want to be able to search, use something like [tag;select2] to convert it to a searchable drop down.

Comment: but with what can i change the google link when i want the js code select a specefic page among other pages

Comment: Change the google link to the pages/files you created.

Comment: i did that, but it keep telling me that the page isnt found eventhou the path is correct

Comment: Please update your post to include your attempt with your own files. A screenshot of your directory structure may be helpful too.

Comment: i tried to put a screenshot but they said i cant post a picture yet so im gonna describe the folder structure, i have a home.html and function.js that does the work ans states.js (it contains all the states as a variables) and there are 48 other html files, each one named after the name of a state, i want to make the function.js choose between those 48 html files to show the right one

Comment: It sounds like they are all in the same directory. You haven't yet shown your attempt to use your files in your code.

Comment: yes the html files are all in the same directory, ive edited the post now with my attempt

Comment: What is `htmls` in `htmls/?q=${selectData}`? Doesn't seem like a file name. It should be something like `${selectData}.html`

Comment: htmls is the directory where i stored my html pages, so the programe has to go to this folder and choode one of the html files

Comment: Then simply add the filename `${selectData}.html` after the directory and remove the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `linkTag.click().click()`, how about using `location.href = webLink`. This way, it'll directly replace the browser url and will input exactly the value of webLink. Also, it won't propagate events.